# jquery - attach/detach multiple divs onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the content of the divs on checkbox's check/un-check events.

HTML:

```
<div class="checks">
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-1" value="section-1">check-1
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-2" value="section-2">check-2
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-3" value="section-3">check-3
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-4" value="section-4">check-4
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-5" value="section-5">check-5
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-6" value="section-6">check-6
        <input type="checkbox" class="section-7" value="section-7">check-7
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="divs">
        <div class="section-1">
            <div class="content-1">
                div-1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-2">
            <div class="content-2">
                div-2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-3">
            <div class="content-3">
                div-3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-4">
            <div class="content-4">
                div-4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-5">
            <div class="content-5">
                div-5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-6">
            <div class="content-6">
                div-6
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-7">
            <div class="content-7">
                div-7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divs-back" style="display: none">
        <div class="section-1">
            <div class="content-1">
                div-1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-2">
            <div class="content-2">
                div-2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-3">
            <div class="content-3">
                div-3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-4">
            <div class="content-4">
                div-4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-5">
            <div class="content-5">
                div-5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-6">
            <div class="content-6">
                div-6
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-7">
            <div class="content-7">
                div-7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
                $(":checkbox:lt(7)").prop("checked", true);
            var array = ["section-1", "section-2", "section-3", "section-4", "section-5", "section-6", "section-7"];
            var unArray = [];
            var unChecked = 0;
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    // Add the new element if checked:
                    if (array.indexOf($(this).val()) < 0) {
                        array.push($(this).val());
                        unChecked = unArray.slice(-1)[0];
                        unArray.splice(-1, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Remove the element if unchecked:
                    if (array.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
                        array.splice(array.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
                        unArray.push($(this).val());
                        unChecked = 0;
                    }
                }
                showHideDiv($(this).val(), unChecked);
                console.log(array);
                console.log(unArray);
            });

        function showHideDiv(value, unCheked) {
            console.log(unCheked);
            if (unCheked != '0') {
                $('.divs').find("." + unCheked).html($('.divs-back').find("." + value).html());
            } else {
                $('.divs').find("." + value).html('');
            }
        }
```

It is replacing the contents successfully on first attempt. But on the second attempt, the positions of the div contents are changed so not getting the desired output.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2th5gmLa/

**Edit:**
Actually, I don't want to just hide show. I want to replace the div content on last unchecked section. When I uncheck `Section-1`, `Section-2`, `Section-3`, then if we check `section-1`, then it should place in the DIV of the `Section-3`.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your code is not working?**

The issue is you are pushing element. The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

> //array.push($(this).val());
>
> remove this line

**Change you have to make.**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var unchkdArray = [];
    var chkdArrray = [];
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       chkdArrray.push($(this).val())
    } else {
        unchkdArray.push($(this).val())
    }
  });
  
  var selected = $(this).val()
  
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('div.' + selected).show()
  } else {
    $('div.' + selected).hide()
  }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2th5gmLa/3/)

Comment: It's okay Sir @Rino Raj please change it

Comment: @IvinRaj If you have any suggestions please leave a comment.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to just hide show. I want to replace the div content on last unchecked section. When Section-1, Section-2, Section-3 is unchecked, then if we check section-1, then it should place in the DIV of the Section-3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

[Plunker Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wusogdoq/)

```
 $(":checkbox:lt(7)").prop("checked", true);
        var array = ["section-1", "section-2", "section-3", "section-4", "section-5", "section-6", "section-7"];
        var unArray = [];
        var unChecked = 0;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

                    console.log($(this)['context']['className']);
                  $( ".divs ."+$(this)['context']['className'] ).toggleClass( "hide" )


        });
```

[Plunker Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wusogdoq/)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to just hide show. I want to replace the div content on last unchecked section. When Section-1, Section-2, Section-3 is unchecked, then if we check section-1, then it should place in the DIV of the Section-3.